# Revert WP Rocket delay javascript execution

Tags: javascript, wordpress, lazy-loading, elementor

I'm developing a player which works with a JS script **inline** that mounts the player in the page. The reason to use a JS script to do it, is prevent the lazy loading on Wordpress/Elementor pages, which often lazy load images and iframes. But there is some users that have been installed WP Rocket with [Delay Javascript execution](https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/1349-delay-javascript-execution?utm_source=wp_plugin&utm_medium=wp_rocket) function enabled. This function makes player's mounting stuck until user scroll the page or move the mouse, it happens coz this function adds `type="rocketlazyloadscript"` to any script inline tag, which makes them run only when it goes out (when user trigger an use event like move the mouse). what could i do to
protect my script tag against this WP Rocket function?

Update: just adding `?nowprocket` for external scripts src fixes it, or `// nowprocket` for in inline scripts

Comment: You could just ask your users to add your script to WP Rocket's "Exclude JavaScript Files" field, warning them that not doing so might prevent the player from working as expected. Either that or you'll need to check with the WP Rocket team whether they provide some filter hook to programmatically exclude specific scripts from being deferred by WP Rocket.

Comment: isn't there any other way to break this?

Comment: Add your page to WP Rocket's issues list: https://github.com/wp-media/wp-rocket/issues . They regularly release an updated list of Delay JS exclusions: https://wp-rocket.me/changelog/.

Comment: You might be able to exclude your script with the `rocket_delay_js_exclusions` filter

Answer (score 0):

Adding a unique keyword or script `id` from your script into the Delay JavaScript Execution box would exclude it from the feature.

If what you are developing(-ed) is a plugin, you can reach out to support to add it to be part of the optional one click exclusions that shows on the Delay JavaScript Execution feature parameters.